# Seeing The Late Show with Stephen Colbert

Tags: new-york-city

https://www.showclix.com/event/TheLateShowwithStephenColb604314 recommends "you get in line no later than 15 minutes prior to 3:15pm". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Show_with_David_Letterman says that that the show is "recorded Monday through Wednesdays at 4:30 p.m., and Thursdays at 3:30 p.m. and 6:00 p.m. Eastern Time. The second Thursday episode usually aired on Friday of that week.

So is the 3:15pm suggestion for M-W or is it also valid for both Thursday filmings as well?

And even if 3:15pm is the latest you'll be allowed in line is it reasonable to get in line at 3:15pm and still get tickets or should you expect to be in line a lot earlier than that?

Comment: You realize that nobody is going to have experience of seeing a recording of Stephen Colbert's Late Show?

Comment: It is my assumption that it'll be filmed at the same times as the Late Show with David Letterman. Like I don't imagine the procedure for getting a white house tour changes from president to president - it's the same regardless of the president and I imagine the same would be true of the Late Show, regardless of who the host is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't like showclix you can go to the horse's mouth:

- [The Late Show with Steve Colbert](http://www.colbertnewshub.com/ticket-information-2/):

> **What Time Show I Arrive?**
>
> It is recommended that you are in line no later than 3PM. Your guests may join you in line up until 3:15PM.  No one will be permitted to join the line after 3:15PM.

So yes arrive by 3pm.

Comment: If they do two showings on Thursdays - one at 3:30pm and one at 6pm - and you're supposed to show up at 3-3:15pm then how do they know which showing you're trying to watch? It just seems weird. On M-W you wait up to 1.25h but on Thursday you wait either 0.25h or 2.75h?

Comment: @neubert And why do you think they care which one you will get into?  Since shows are overbooked as is there will always be someone to take your seat. :)

Comment: @neubert They could simply do it in order of appearance...